# Populate a new column in one table based on start and end dates in another table

Tags: r

I have a larger data table (called raw.data) and a smaller one (called balldrop.times) listing the start and end times of an event.

I want to create a new column in the larger data table that will fill up the times between the event start and end date that are located in the smaller table. The times that aren't between the event start/end time can be labeled something else, it doesn't really matter.

```
#the dput of the smaller table
> dput(balldrop.times)
structure(list(Stage = 6:14, 
BallStart = structure(c(1635837081, 1635847841, 1635856675, 1635866152, 1635878326, 1635886132, 1635895547, 1635902934, 1635911136), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
BallEnd = structure(c(1635837364, 1635848243, 1635857005, 1635866475, 1635878704, 1635886465, 1635895905, 1635903786, 1635911457), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

#here is part of the larger table just in case
> dput(head(raw.data, 5))
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1635825603.6576, 1635825604.608, 1635825605.6448, 1635825606.6816, 1635825607.632), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
Press.Well = c(1154.2561461, 1154.0308849, 1149.7247783, 1152.0544566, 1155.7363779), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000020725b51ef0>)
```

My desired output is something like the following, with "Event Active" only for the times between the listed DateTime vales in the balldrop.times table:

| DateTime | Press.Well | Event Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-02 02:11:20 | 10 | Event Not Active |
| 2021-11-02 02:11:21 | 10 | Event Active |
| 2021-11-02 02:11:22 | 15 | Event Active |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-11-02 02:16:04 | 25 | Event Active |
| 2021-11-02 02:16:05 | 30 | Event Not Active |

I am thinking I can use `mutate()` to create a new column in the raw.data table and set conditions for the DateTime, but I am not sure how to do this for multiple separate start/end DateTimes.

Any help would be appericated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a desired output according your inputs? Also, the result  _"Event Active"_ is given if the nth `DateTime` in `raw.data` is between any of the couples of datas in `balldrop.times`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working. Neither do the times in your example table correspond with the ones in your expected output.

```
tmp <- structure(list(Stage = 6:14, 
               BallStart = structure(c(1635837081, 1635847841, 1635856675, 1635866152, 1635878326, 1635886132, 1635895547, 1635902934, 1635911136), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
               BallEnd = structure(c(1635837364, 1635848243, 1635857005, 1635866475, 1635878704, 1635886465, 1635895905, 1635903786, 1635911457), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
               ), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

tmp1 <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1635825603.6576, 1635825604.608, 1635825605.6448, 1635825606.6816, 1635825607.632), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"),
                      Press.Well = c(1154.2561461, 1154.0308849, 1149.7247783, 1152.0544566, 1155.7363779) ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

So note this isn't a clean solution.

```
tmp1 %>% 
  mutate(`Event Status` = case_when(
    DateTime >= (tmp[1,] %>% pull(BallStart)) & DateTime <= (tmp[1,] %>% pull(BallEnd)) ~ "Event Active",
    DateTime >= (tmp[2,] %>% pull(BallStart)) & DateTime <= (tmp[2,] %>% pull(BallEnd)) ~ "Event Active",
    DateTime >= (tmp[3,] %>% pull(BallStart)) & DateTime <= (tmp[3,] %>% pull(BallEnd)) ~ "Event Active",
    DateTime >= (tmp[4,] %>% pull(BallStart)) & DateTime <= (tmp[4,] %>% pull(BallEnd)) ~ "Event Active",
    DateTime >= (tmp[5,] %>% pull(BallStart)) & DateTime <= (tmp[5,] %>% pull(BallEnd)) ~ "Event Active",
    TRUE ~ "Event Not Active"
  ))
```

Because you want to compare multiple conditions, `case_when` is the preferred option rather than `ifelse`. With that I compare it to every row in your reference table.

Now, like said it isn't a clean solution as you have many rows to specify it. With a bigger reference table to check the code will increase exponentionally. But you can clean it up into a function.